# Динамическое преобразование объекта в массив

Tags: javascript

```
const obj = {
  AREA_OBJECTS: '10',
  ELECTRICITY: '20',
  EXTERNAL_TRANSPORT: '30',
  SINGLE_WELL: '40',
};
```

хочу получить такой массив

```
const array = [
   {id:AREA_OBJECTS, value:'10'},
   {id:ELECTRICITY, value:'20'},
   {id:EXTERNAL_TRANSPORT, value:'30'},
   {id:SINGLE_WELL, value:'40'}
 ]
```

мой вариант

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach((a) => {
  return {
    id: Object.values(obj[a])[0],
    value: obj[a],
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

С помощью метода [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) можно получить список пар ключ-значение

Дальше с помощью метода [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) отобразить полученный массив на массив с нужными элементами:

```js
const obj = {
  AREA_OBJECTS: '10',
  ELECTRICITY: '20',
  EXTERNAL_TRANSPORT: '30',
  SINGLE_WELL: '40',
};

console.log(Object.entries(obj).map(([id, value]) => ({
  id,
  value
})))
```